# Spring MVC Test with Hamcrest: How compare a XML's node directly against a Java object

Tags: xml, xpath, spring-test-mvc

I am working with:

- Spring MVC Test
- Hamcrest

For an item from a collection such as:

```
<collection>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="persona">
        <id>087</id>
        <nombre>Leonardo</nombre>
        <apellido>Jordan</apellido>
        <fecha>1981-07-05</fecha>
    </item>
    ....
```

The following works:

```
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]").exists())
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/*").nodeCount(is(4)))
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/id").exists())
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/id").string(is("087")))
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/id").string(is(personasArray[0].getId())))
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/nombre").exists())
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/nombre").string(is("Leonardo")))
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/nombre").string(is(personasArray[0].getNombre())))
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/apellido").exists())
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/apellido").string(is("Jordan")))
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/apellido").string(is(personasArray[0].getApellido())))
```

I want to know if is possible do a direct comparison against an object and not for each field, consider an entity with 15 to 45 fields.

I need something like this:

```
.andExpect(xpath("collection/item[1]/*").how(is(personasArray[0])))
```

See the `how` part, it represents what is the correct method to use.
Same consideration for the `path`'s String content.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do such an assertion. But you'll need to write your custom [`ResultMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.3.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/ResultMatcher.html) for that. I don't think it is a good idea to convert XML (nodes) to Java objects just to do a simple comparison in a unit test.
You may run into problems with XML namespace resolution or the Java `hashCode` `equals` contract if not implemented right.

Instead, you should use libraries that lets you focus on your unit tests and not on the details of a technology or a programming language.

I recommend you to use [`XMLUnit`](https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunit) in your test. `XMLUnit` is a Java library for XML comparison.

The example below depicts how easy it is to compare a XML document with XMLUnit and a custom `ResultMatcher`.

```
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.xmlunit.builder.Input;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.xmlunit.matchers.CompareMatcher.isSimilarTo;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(XmlUnitDemoTests.XmlUnitDemo.class)
public class XmlUnitDemoTests {

    static final String XML_CONTENT = "<node1><node2 id=\"1\">text</node2></node1>";

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void xmlUnit() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/xml"))
            .andExpect(xml(XML_CONTENT));
    }

    static ResultMatcher xml(String bodyValue) {
        return MockMvcResultMatchers.content().source(equalXml(bodyValue));
    }

    static Matcher equalXml(String value) {
        return isSimilarTo(Input.fromString(value).build());
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    @RestController
    static class XmlUnitDemo {

        @RequestMapping(value = "xml", produces = "text/xml")
        String xml() {
            return XML_CONTENT;
        }
    }

}
```

Of course, you may load big XML files from classpath or select a node with XPatch before doing a comparison. Take a look at the `XMLUnit` documentation for more information on that.

Comment: Thanks by your post, I will check your valuable suggestion. Now about `I don't think it is a good idea to convert XML (nodes) to Java objects just to do a simple comparison in a unit test` I would be agree. I understand your point, of course is valid, but I must assume that the remote client has a OXM technology. I work with Jackson for `XML` and `JSON`.

Comment: You have better inside into your project setup and you are the only one who can made the right decision. I just want to share my opinion and experience with you.

Comment: I am not saying your opinion is wrong. I am agree, but my point is do `quick` the `@Test` codification. Imagine if you add or do refactoring to the domain classes. I will test your suggestion. It is valuable. All is Ok. Thanks again by your post.

Comment: I just want to say in a polite way that you know the bits and bytes of your project and hence only you can decide whether option a or b is better applicable.  No pun intended here. Keep on rollin :-)